# Small Height of Iframe Facebook Comment box has blocked content

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-comments

I am using Facebook comment plugin, due to limited iframe height causing admin box and sometimes comments box could not show completely (Please see the attached).
Any suggestion can do to prevent this kind of error happen[image]?

Answer (score 0):

In this case iFrame height is influenced by the height of the parent element. Find the parent and try to increase the height of the parent.

Comment: I tried to increase the height of parent iframe but it is not a perfect way when there have more comments within the iframe. The comments will overlapping the original content.

Comment: Instead make the parent a div. Do not assign any height attribute and see it reacts to the fb iframe height.

Comment: After removed the height attribute, whole comment contents all can't show.